# Ckeditor add voice recorder recordmp3js plugin

Tags: voice, recorder, ckeditor.net

I want add voice recorder plugin to CKEditor, but I can't configure. Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: you tried ?, shows the code that you have

Comment: which code? i download recordmp3js plugin and added into plugins. after this what can i do?

Comment: hey
got any solution ?